# Passar array em rota Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Preciso passar um array para um controller. Fiz da forma abaixo mas me retorna o erro:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: site.add.cart] [URI: adiciona-carrinho/{product}/{option}]. (View: /var/www/html/ecommerce/resources/views/site/pages/product/product.blade.php)
```

View:

```
<div class="col-12 offset-lg-6">
    @php
        $array = [1, 2];
    @endphp
    <a id="add-cart" href="{{ route('site.add.cart', ['product' => $product, 'option' => serialize($array)]) }}" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Adicionar ao Carrinho</a>
</div>
```

Rota:

```
Route::get('/adiciona-carrinho/{product}/{option}', 'CartController@addCart')->name('site.add.cart');
```

Controller

```
public function addCart(Product $product, $option)
{
    dd($option);

}
```

Comment: Você precisa passar o paramentro option, sem ser serializado, e trabalhar essa informação no `controller`? entendeu

Comment: Mas preciso passar um array na rota. Vi em outra pergunta o uso do serialize  dessa forma. Acabei conseguindo passar com json_encode mas queria saber pq o serialize nao funciona.

Comment: Por causa do formato de saída do `serialize`, agora como você consegiu passar com `js_encode` que seria um `json` , coloque isso como resposta! se não a sua pergunta não tem validade, não vai ajudar ninguém

Answer (score 1):

Consegui passar o array com json_encode() e depois usando json_decode() no controller.

```
<div class="col-12 offset-lg-6">
    @php
        $array = [1, 2];
    @endphp
    <a id="add-cart" href="{{ route('site.add.cart', ['product' => $product, 'option' => json_encode($array)]) }}" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Adicionar ao Carrinho</a>
</div>
```

Rota:

```
Route::get('/adiciona-carrinho/{product}/{option}', 'CartController@addCart')->name('site.add.cart');
```

Controller:

```
public function addCart(Product $product, $option)
{
    json_decode($option);
    dd($option);
}
```